# search in a string creditcard numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find a credit card numeric value in a sql string.

for example;

```
DECLARE @value1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'The payment is the place 1234567812345678'
DECLARE @value2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'The payment is the place 123456aa7812345678'
DECLARE @value3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'The payment1234567812345678is the place'
```

The result should be :

```
@value1Result 1234567812345678
@value2Result NULL
@value3Result 1234567812345678
```

16 digits must be together without space.

How to do this in a sql script or a function?

edit : 
if I want to find these 2 credit card value.

```
@value4 = 'card 1 is : 4034349183539301 and the other one is 3456123485697865'
```

how should I implement the scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as:

```
SELECT case when Len(LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1)) = 16
                 then LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1)
                 else ''
                 end
FROM (
    SELECT subsrt = SUBSTRING(string, pos, LEN(string))
    FROM (
        SELECT string, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string)
        FROM table1
    ) d
) t
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/ATUQ50495)</kbd>

Comment: @Deepshikka; If the text like this 'card 1 is :  4034349183539301 and the other one is 3456123485697865' How to find this 2 card number value in your script?

Answer (score 4):

You can use PathIndex as

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', yourStr)
```

if the result is 0 then it doesnt containg 16 digits other was it contains.

It can be used withing a `Where` statement or `Select` statement based on your needs

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @value1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'card 1 is : 4034349183539301 and the other one is 3456123485697865'
DECLARE @Lenght INT
    ,@Count INT
    ,@Candidate CHAR
    ,@cNum INT
    ,@result VARCHAR(16)

SELECT @Count = 1

SELECT @cNum = 0

SELECT @result = ''

SELECT @Lenght = LEN(@value1)

WHILE @Count <= @Lenght
BEGIN
    SELECT @Candidate = SUBSTRING(@value1, @Count, 1)

```
IF @Candidate != ' '
    AND ISNUMERIC(@Candidate) = 1
BEGIN
    SET @cNum = @cNum + 1
    SET @result = @result + @Candidate
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @cNum = 1
    SET @result = ''
END

IF @cNum > 16
BEGIN
    SELECT @result 'Credit Number'
END

SET @Count = @Count + 1
```

END

Comment: If the text like this 'card 1 is : 4034349183539301 and the other one is 3456123485697865' How to find this 2 card number value in your script?

Answer (score 0):

There you go kind sir.

```
 DECLARE 
    @value3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'The payment1234567812345678is the place',
    @MaxCount int,
    @Count int,
    @Numbers NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Count = 1
SELECT @Numbers = ''
SELECT @MaxCount = LEN(@value3)


WHILE @Count <= @MaxCount
BEGIN

    IF (UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@value3,@Count,1)) >= 48 AND UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@value3,@Count,1)) <=57)
        SELECT @Numbers = @Numbers + SUBSTRING(@value3,@Count,1)

    SELECT @Count = @Count + 1


END
PRINT @Numbers
```

You can make this as a function if you are planning to use it a lot.

Comment: This will just find the last word. Which fails for the OP's `@value2` and `@value3` examples.

Comment: My apologies i fixed it and now it should work in all cases :)